# My code is not auto redirecting to login page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

So I am creating this registration and activation page..

So let's say User name is John..
John enters the registration page and fills in his name, email and password.
After clicking the submit button, my web app sends an activation link to John's email.
John clicks on the link and it successfully activated his account(as per checking in my database and testing on actual website, it is indeed working. It loads the activation page that just says "account activated. you will be redirected to login page to log into your account"
However, it is not redirecting to the login page..

My login page link is " http://localhost:3000/login "

This is my activation page .jsx file.. Which i made..
I've been trying to debug this for quite awhile but i am stuck. Even with ChatGPT
Sorry if newbie question, but i am indeed new but trying very hard !!

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const ActivationPage = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("Activating your account...");
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    const activateAccount = async () => {
      const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
      const token = params.get('token');
    
      if (token) {
        try {
          const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/auth/activate?token=${token}`);
          setMessage(response.data);          
        } catch (error) {
          setMessage('Failed to activate account. Please try again.');
          return;
        }
        setTimeout(() => {
          navigate('/login');
        }, 1000);
      }
    };
    
    activateAccount();
  }, [navigate]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Account Activation</h1>
      <p>{message}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ActivationPage;
```

Comment: I don't see any way for the code you've provided here to ***not*** navigate to `"/login"` a second after mounting and running the effect. Are you saying that the URL path isn't updating to `"/login"`? Are there any errors generated that would have halted the Javascript execution? Please [edit] to clarify the issue/problem and provide any additional debugging information you may have. Include a more complete [mcve] of the routing/navigation code as well.

Comment: Yes not updating to ./login.

My backend is working as intended, i feel like its just the frontend but i cannot seem to pinpoint the issue.
Dont see error on my console logging as well. 
Leaving me more puzzled

Comment: Is `token` a truthy value so the if-block is executed? If so, how far into that block does the code get through? Set a breakpoint and step through the code to see if/when `navigate("/login")` is called.

Comment: Yes, token is truthy. that is why the axios.get got activated. and in turn it does activates the user account(from isActivated = false to isActivated = true). Thus, user is allowed to log in.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the navigation logic is included in the useEffect dependency array, which may not be necessary. **I recommend removing it and placing the navigation code after the setMessage function call**. Additionally, consider removing the setTimeout function if you find it unnecessary. This adjustment should ensure a smoother login process.

Comment: Followed your suggestion but still not redirecting. 

Below my updated code:

if (token) {
        try {
          const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/auth/activate?token=${token}`);
          setMessage(response.data); 
          navigate('/login');         
        } catch (error) {
          setMessage('Failed to activate account. Please try again.');
          console.error('Error activating account:', error);
        }
      }
    };

    activateAccount();
  }, [navigate]);

Comment: please sure about your data 
sometimes you need more data for example : 
response.data.data 
you can check it with log